# Suma de dos numeros en punto flotante mediante funcion inline asm en C

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Estoy trabajando con gcc en linux , tengo una implementación de una función asm inline ,la cual suma dos números en punto flotante y los retorna por referencia en la variable r pasada también como parámetro, compila pero el resultado de la suma es 0.0, alguien podría ayudarme , gracias :) aqui mi función:

```
   #define suma(r, a, b)\
   __asm__("fldz \n\t fld %1\n\t fadd %2\n\t fstp %0":"=&t"(r):"f"(a),"f"(b));
```

Comment: ¿En serio esto es necesario? ¿Por qué no dejas la suma en código C++?

Comment: Estoy intentando aprender ensamblador , por eso lo hago, solo que utilizo el compilador de c y funciones inline, para no andar creando archivos.asm compilarlos,linkarlos..

Comment: Para aprender ensamblador deja de lado C y trabaja directamente en ensamblador... embeber ensamblador en código C no es algo necesariamente sencillo ya que hay que tener en cuenta bastantes detalles que te alejan de lo que realmente te importa, que es aprender ensamblador

Comment: Bueno mi interés es en aprender ensamblador para poder embeberlo en C , si puedes ayudarme con la función te lo agradecería

Comment: Yo lo pregunto porque salvo casos muy muy concretos, embeber ensamblador no proporciona **absolutamente ninguna mejora** e incluso el código que se genera es de peor calidad, no portable y muy sensible a los errores

Comment: Gracias por tu recomendacion , practicare ensamblador directamente aunque aun no se muy bien como retornar el valor de los registros a C, aun asi me gustaria resolver mi duda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con un par de cambios he conseguido que funcione, al menos en mi máquina:

```
#define suma(r, a, b)\
  __asm__("FLD %1 \n FADD %2 \n FSTP %0 \n" : "=m"(r) : "m"(f1), "m"(f2) : );

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  float f;
  float f1 = 4, f2 = 5;
  suma(f,f1,f2);
  printf("%f, %f, %f",f,f1,f2);
}
```

Las restricciones utilizadas para las variables no parecían ser las correctas y además estabas haciendo operaciones innecesarias: `fldz`

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ayudo, apuntar que en tu respuesta en la definicion de la macro suma, usas f1 y f2, supongo que habra sido fallo al escribir , deberian ir a y b respectivamente. En cuanto a las restricciones , sabia que iban pot ahi los tiros , mire en la documentacion de intel y vi que "f","g" se usaban para nombrar numeros de punto flotante. Parece ser que no era asi. Sabrias o podrias decirme decirme donde puedo ver el significado de esa restriccion por ejemplo("m"). Muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Vale olvida lo ultimo ya encontre el significado de las restricciones, el problema es que "f","t" y "u" son registros en si . Osea mi codigo inicial tambien puede arreglarse poniendo el modificador register a las variables :) aunq claro esto no es seguro . Pero entendi la diferencia entre las restricciones .Gracias